# How to resolve SchedulingDisabled status to running in kubernetes kubectl node

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am trying to configure a basic mongodb container in kubernetes.

I am using *minikube* and *kubectl*.

My OS is Macbook Pro version Version 14.1.1.

Here are the specs:

1. **Processor** : *2.7 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7*
2. **Graphics** : *Intel Iris Plus Graphics 655 1536 MB*
3. **Memory** : *16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3*

**Storage Status** : *83.17 GB available of 250.69 GB*

This is my configuration file mongo.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongodb
          image: mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          env:
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-username
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-password
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

This is my mongo-secret.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mongodb-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  mongo-root-username: <user-name>
  mongo-root-password: <password>
```

I have run the following commands in order after getting `minikube start`

```
kubectl apply -f mongo-secret.yaml
```

Then, I ran this command:

```
kubectl apply -f mongo.yaml
```

After this when I ran :

```
kubectl get nodes
```

This is the output:

```
NAME       STATUS                     ROLES           AGE   VERSION
minikube   Ready,SchedulingDisabled   control-plane   43h   v1.28.3
```

Then I tried to check if the pods are up:

`kubectl get pod --watch`

This was the output:

```
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mongodb-deployment-699744c7d-kdjl6   0/1     Pending   0          35m
```

Then I looked further into the pod:

`kubectl describe pod mongodb-deployment-699744c7d-kdjl6`

This is the output:

```
Name:             mongodb-deployment-699744c7d-kdjl6
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             <none>
Labels:           app=mongodb
                  pod-template-hash=699744c7d
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Pending
IP:               
IPs:              <none>
Controlled By:    ReplicaSet/mongodb-deployment-699744c7d
Containers:
  mongodb:
    Image:      mongo
    Port:       27017/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME:  <set to the key 'mongo-root-username' in secret 'mongodb-secret'>  Optional: false
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'mongo-root-password' in secret 'mongodb-secret'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-gppjl (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-gppjl:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  93s (x6 over 39m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) were unschedulable. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling..
```

Can someone let me know what to do here? Am I missing any step?

P.S: I am a newbie to kubernetes so any help is appreciated to get it running smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information at hand, ‘SchedulingDisabled’ could be caused by several factors. You can start off by checking the status of minikube and the logs so you can verify if there are errors that can lead to where the problem is residing.

‘minikube status’

‘kubectl describe node minikube’

‘minikube logs’

From here check the Network connectivity and the resources of your minikube that can be culprits on why the nodes won't schedule. Lastly, make sure that the version of your minikube is up to date to avoid any incompatibility issues. Last resort would be deleting your minikube and restarting but make sure you have backup for it may cause data loss.

Comment: Thankyou Ray, I installed `kube-capacity` tool to understand the capacity of resources and everything went good.

Then, I checked the hostport which was causing no conflicts with the cluster.

So, I did the steps mentioned in the solution and it started to work. Hence, I posted it here too.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Another confession is that I forget to check the logs and only focused on `minikube describe`. So, anyone else who gets into it should see the logs too.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and then I got the solution.

Here is what I did:

1. I ssh into the node `ssh minikube`
2. Identify the kubelet processes `ps aux | grep kubelet`
3. Stop the kubelet service `sudo kill <kubelet_pid>`
4. Start the kubelet service `sudo systemctl start kubelet`
5. Verified the kubelet Status `sudo systemctl status kubelet`

Then I restarted the node:

1. `kubectl drain <node_name>`
2. SSH into the node and Rebooted `sudo reboot`
3. Uncorned the node `kubectl uncordon <node_name>`

And then ping the node ip.

It worked well.

And the pod and node are in running status.